# iOS Accessibility VoiceOver

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, voiceover

I'm trying to read text using **voice over**. There is **date** included in part of string.
For displaying this **mm/d/yyyy** format is used.

But for VoiceOver I need to use **MMMM d, yyyy**.

While VoiceOver happens automatically, it reads in format **MMMM d, yyyy**. But on swiping text in UITextView it reads display format(i.e **mm/d/yyyy**).

How to read date in this format (i.e **MMMM d, yyyy**) while **swiping**.

Am using **attributed text** for displaying value in **UITextView**

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `accessibilityLabel` property of the `UILabel`? That gives you the opportunity to define the string that will be read out, so you can use a different dateFormat for it

Comment: Yes but this is for UITextView. **accessibilityLabel** is working but we can select lines in textview. That causes the issues.